# Al Hamichya in one room and al hagefen in another room

Tags: halacha, blessing

If you eat cake in Room A and then proceed to drink wine in Room B both *bracha achronas* must be made in the rooms in which the food was eaten. Where and how do you make a *bracha achrona*. Here are the choices:

1. Make a single bracha of *Al haMichya ve'al hagefen* in Room A
2. Make a single bracha of *Al haMichya ve'al hagefen* in Room B
3. Make the bracha of *Al haMichya* in Room A and a separate bracha of *al hagefen* in Room B

Sourced answers only, please.